# plausibility check : this kind of mushroom

Tags: internal-consistency, fungi

context :

- in this world with small gravity and strong wind, airbone plants thrive.
- this planet too have thick clouds covering so underneath it is almost dark or rainy.
- the thriveness of airbone plants can be rooted since they got most of the sun above.
- most of animal life thrive above land.
- in the land however, a unique species of mushroom evolve
- they have developed a way to eat : by filtering the rain water. as since life thrive in the air, their waste got stuck in the clouds. so when the rain down, so is the waste.
- so this mushroom evolve to eat by filtering the rain water from above,eating out all the waste from it.

how plausible is this ?

Comment: The mushroom seems fine, but airborne plants are fairly dubious.

Comment: the plant is algae like.

Comment: This is how real fungi work.

Comment: Plausibility is highly dependent upon how much an audience is willing to suspend disbelief. Depending on how you present your mushrooms you will get  vastly different levels of plausibility. As such as written just asking "Is this thing plausible?" is a very opinion based question.

Comment: What if the plants are balloon-like? Not fully airborne, but, rooted to the ground, they could also naturally have helium in them to make them float. There would be a problem with that though because helium is a rare gas and being rooted to the earth has the risk of being detached and floating away.

Comment: How does the planet retain its atmosphere? Low gravity and a thick atmosphere won't co-exist for geological timespans, AFAICS.

Comment: @Kijivu I would think it much more plausible that a balloon-plant produces Methane or Hydrogen for lift-gas. Though the range of gases that would be suitable as lift-gas get wider as the atmosphere thickens.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, it's plausible**

Your mushroom works pretty much as real mushrooms work, so there is really nothing to complain about there. There are no comparable airborne ecosystems on earth, but you could build it analogous to oceanic ecosystem, so yes, it's also plausible. Although, being analogous to oceans would mean there are different zones in it, not only Clouds and Surface, there would be some life between them, pretty sparse though.